# Detecting when jquery ui datepicker is empty

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using a Jquery ui datepicker as follows:

```
 <input type="text" name="StartDate" id="StartDate" class="date-picker" />   
 <input type="text" name="FinishDate" id="FinishDate" class="date-picker" />
```

in my JS

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date) {  
           alert("selected!");
        }
    });
```

Is there a way to detect when the user left the datepicker empty similar to the way selection is detected as above?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you're looking for the `onClose` callback: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B9XD/3/)

```
$("input").datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText){
        if( !dateText ){
            alert('empty!');
        }
    }
});
```